# Babelify is importing modules correctly, but they aren't getting transpiled

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, browserify, babeljs

I'm having trouble transpiling node modules written with es6 syntax. I am writing js using es6 myself and my files get transpiled correctly, but modules from node_modules folder don't. They get imported correctly though. I am using gulp with this setup

```
gulp.task('scripts', function () {
  var bundler = browserify({
    entries: paths.src + 'scripts/main.js',
    presets: ["es2015"],
    extensions: ['.js'],
    debug: true
  });
  bundler.transform(babelify);
  bundler.bundle()
    .on('error', function (err) { console.log(err); })
    .pipe(source('main.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dest + 'scripts'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```

Comment: **Please read tag descriptions!** [tag:babel] says: *"Python internationalization library with an emphasis on web-based applications. For questions about the JavaScript library, please use [babeljs]."*

Comment: Do you really want to transpile code in node_modules? `node_modules` is intentionally excluded from transforms of browserify because it usually contains ES5 code that doesn't require transpilation.